# Пожалуйста помогите когда устанавливаю npm

Tags: https

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда устанавливаю npm install такое сообшения помоему надо поменят порт  443 на 8080  но не знаю как <>

Comment: Попробуйте установить с флагом `-d`. Либо `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: не получается!?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7945, либо `npm config set proxy null`